# Wikitude not working after apply proguard

Tags: android, wikitude

Wikitude is not working after applying proguard. There is no error in log.
If I remove proguard then it works fine.

Comment: Help me ASAP? that's not how it works .Apart from that your question vague . Please add more information to your question. `build.gradle` .

Comment: @ADM, Sorry for this. I'll keep in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try:

> -keep class com.wikitude.** { *; }

[Find more details at the proguard website.](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/examples.html)

Comment: Thank you very much. You saved my day :)